# Extension for original zsh _hosts completion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

Before start, I'd like to give some context.

A couple of years ago I implemented an autocompletion function for one particular case: [querying all hosts from database](https://github.com/innogames/serveradmin/blob/master/zsh-completion/adminapi#L13).

It has a couple of flows. One of the most - rewriting and losing original completion.

That's why after some evenings I've implemented the new approach. Now the function preserves the original one and extends it. As well it runs in the background and doesn't lock the console. The [sources](https://github.com/Felixoid/zsh-hoco/blob/master/hoco.zsh#L41-L105) are on github, but I'll post it here as well

```
# Preserve _hosts as _hosts_orig, but only once
if ! (( $_HOCO_INIT_DONE )); then
  typeset -g _HOCO_INIT_DONE=1

  # _hosts needs to be intiated before tweaking
  _hosts 2>/dev/null >&1 || true

  eval "$(type -f _hosts | sed -r '1 s/_hosts/_hosts_orig/')"
fi

__hosts_cache_callback() {
  ((_HOCO_RUNNING_JOBS--))

  # It's 99.9% impossible to have empty original _cache_hosts,
  # but it's checked before filling originally. We should wait untill it's set
  while (( $+_cache_hosts == 0 )); do
    sleep 0.1
  done

  # $2: exit status; $3: stdout
  [[ "$2" == 0 ]] && _cache_hosts+=("${(f)3}")

  # cleaunup for the last job
  if (( _HOCO_RUNNING_JOBS == 0 )); then
    async_unregister_callback hosts_cache_updater
    async_stop_worker hosts_cache_updater
  fi
}

# Arguments:
# $1 - cache_age
__hosts_cache_update() {
  # if cache age is twice older than ${HOCO_CACHE_TTL:-600}, then it's definitely an issue
  # with long runnung tasks, abort them
  if (( ${HOCO_CACHE_TTL:-600} < ${1} / 2 )); then
    unset _HOCO_UPDATE_RUNNING_SINCE
    async_flush_jobs hosts_cache_updater
    async_unregister_callback hosts_cache_updater
    async_stop_worker hosts_cache_updater
  fi
  (( ${_HOCO_UPDATE_RUNNING_SINCE} )) && return 0
  _HOCO_CACHE_UPDATED=${EPOCHSECONDS}
  unset _cache_hosts

  # starting worker that runs only one unic function with notifications
  async_start_worker hosts_cache_updater -n -u
  async_register_callback hosts_cache_updater __hosts_cache_callback

  _HOCO_RUNNING_JOBS=${#HOCO_FUNCTIONS}
  for func (${HOCO_FUNCTIONS}); do
    async_job hosts_cache_updater ${func}
  done
}

_hosts() {
  # Should be cache updated or not
  local cache_age
  cache_age=$((EPOCHSECONDS - _HOCO_CACHE_UPDATED))
  if (( ${HOCO_CACHE_TTL:-600} < ${cache_age} )); then
    __hosts_cache_update ${cache_age}
  fi

  # original logic
  _hosts_orig
}
```

I've dug quite deep into the ZSH completion system, but maybe I still miss some points that could be useful. That's why I'd like to have my code reviewed.